# Rails, active record. Joining four tables together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am learning ruby on rails and I've run into an active record problem I have been unable to solve. I am trying to inner join four tables together and display data from them.

I have confirmed that my database schema is correct by running the following SQL style query. It returns the data I expect it to.

```
 select * from sailings
 INNER JOIN travelling_parties on sailings.id = travelling_parties.sailing_id
 INNER JOIN party_registers on travelling_parties.id = party_registers.travelling_party_id
 inner JOIN users on party_registers.user_id = users.id
 where users.id = 8
```

After reading through the great docs on guides.rubyonrails.org, I am still unable to find the solution. The below query is what I've come up with in my controller, but it doesn't seem to be return what I need it to.

```
@sailing = Sailing.joins(:travelling_parties => [{:party_registers => :user}])
```

I would appreciate anyone who could steer me in the right direction.

Thanks

EDIT 1: Here are my models. I am attempting to check user.id = current_user.id and display data based on that.

```
class Sailing
  has_many :travelling_parties
end

class TravelingParty
  has_many :party_registers
  has_many :users, through: :party_registers
end

class PartyRegister
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :travelling_party
end

class User
  has_many :party_registers
  has_many :travelling_parties, through: :party_registers
end
```

EDIT 2: The following query gave me my intended results

@sailing = Sailing.joins(:travelling_parties => {:party_registers => :user}).where("users.id" => current_user.id)

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: can u post yr models ? also what exactly wanna return from users table ?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is close to correct *assuming* that you have defined the associations.

```
class Sailing
  belongs_to :traveling_party
end

class TravelingParty
  belongs_to :party_register
end

class PartyRegister
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The

`@sailing = Sailing.joins(:travelling_parties => {:party_registers => :user})`

Comment: I have `class Sailling has_many :travelling_parties, class TravelingParty has_many :party_registers has_many :users, through: :party_registers, class PartyRegister   belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :travelling_party`